# Program crashes after array initialization changed

Tags: c++, arrays, ofstream

So generally I have an object of this structure:

```
typedef struct WAVStream
{
    std::ofstream stream;
    short* outBuffer;
    int* inBuffer;
    char* streamFileName;
    int outBufPosition;
    int sizeCheck;
    int savedParts;
    int savedBytes;
    bool isHeaderCreated;

} WAVStream;
```

And so far this object was initialized that way:

```
WAVStream wavStreams[8];
```

When I display what's inside the fields after initialization then I get 0 everywhere and some memory block address in `std::ofstream field`.

But now I needed to have a possibility to specify array size from config. Because of that `WAVStream wavStreams[size]` - size parameter is not constant. I needed to change my array allocation to:

```
int size = 8;
WAVStream* wavStreams = (WAVStream*) malloc(sizeof(WAVStream) * size);
```

And now my program crash. I don't get any error log, but just crash and I don't know how to debug this. My idea is: to initialize the values in `wavStreams` so it is the same as during previous creation method. For now I see random numbers so to fix it I do:

```
int size = 8;
WAVStream* wavStreams = (WAVStream*) malloc(sizeof(WAVStream) * size);


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    wavStreams[i].inBuffer = 0;
    wavStreams[i].isHeaderCreated = false;
    wavStreams[i].outBuffer = 0;
    wavStreams[i].outBufPosition = 0;
    wavStreams[i].savedBytes = 0;
    wavStreams[i].savedParts = 0;
    wavStreams[i].sizeCheck = 0;
//  wavStreams[i].stream = ???
    wavStreams[i].streamFileName = "";

    cout<< "\n";
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].inBuffer;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].isHeaderCreated;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].outBuffer;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].outBufPosition;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].savedBytes;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].savedParts;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].sizeCheck;
//  cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].stream;
    cout<< " " << wavStreams[i].streamFileName;
    cout<< "\n";
}
```

Whenever I want to touch `std::ofstream` somehow my program crashes. I can't display the value. I don't know how to properly initialize this field. `WAVStream wavStreams[8]` did it on it's own. How to do it manually?

Comment: Use `new` not `malloc`.

Comment: `std::vector<WAVStream>` would be even better here. Keep the [Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) reference on hand at all times. If you want, you can `reserve` memory.

Comment: You cannot `malloc` something containing a class such as `ofstream` .

Comment: After `WAVStream* wavStreams = new WAVStream[size];` I still get crash on `cout << wavStreams[i].stream;` hmm... (problem is that I am not even sure if that's the case why my program doesn't work anymore, but I'd like to have same effect as `WAVStream wavStreams[8]` ). Using vector means... editing a lot.